# Pug file not loading CSS

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, express, pug

I've got an express project set up. I'm using Pug as the view engine.

I've got the following lines in my app.js,

```
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, './views'));
app.set('view engine', 'pug');
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, './public')));
```

And I've got the following in my index.pug view,

```
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/style.css', type='text/css')
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/boostrap.min.css', type='text/css')
```

The CSS files are in the right folders (public/stylesheets), but when I load up the app, the view does not seem to load the CSS files.

The full project with its directories and all the code can be found [here](https://github.com/Humad/pita-pockets-restaurant)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Typo in your link to bootstrap, you have boo**s**trap:

```
link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/boostrap.min.css', type='text/css')
```

Comment: I was getting this error

Refused to apply style from <filepath> because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using pug 2.*, or a greater version, the code below will work

```
html
    head
        style
             include ./style.css
    body
```

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue, bootstrap file was loaded but code has not effect on any bootstrap classes. The issue was that I had a typo on the **rel** attribute. I had *stytesheet* instead of *stylesheet*

```
link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/bootstrap.min.css')
```

Answer (score 0):

My code is working with this one

```
doctype html
html(lang='en')
  head
    link(rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous")

    title Jade
  body
    h1 Jade - node template engine
```